# How to avoid heap allocation inserting Rendercommands to a RenderCommandBuffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, game-engine, heap-memory

I have a RenderQueue that sorts a list of elements to render.
Now that RenderQueue creates a RenderCommandBuffer with all the "low level" rendering operations, the problem is that the performance goes from 1400 FPS to 40FPS for 1000 elements

I profiled the app and the problem lies here (those per frame allocations):

```
        std::for_each(element.meshCommands.begin(), element.meshCommands.end(), [&] (auto &command) {
            std::vector<std::pair<std::string, glm::mat4> > p{ { "MVP", VPmatrix * command.second} };
            m_commandBuffer.addCommand(std::make_shared<SetShaderValuesCommand>(element.material,p));
            m_commandBuffer.addCommand(std::make_shared<BindMaterialCommand>(element.material));
            m_commandBuffer.addCommand(std::make_shared<RenderMeshCommand>(meshProperty.mesh)); 
        });
```

I know that I can group my meshes by material, but the problem is more or less the same. Allocation of many objects per frame. How will you avoid this situation? How the game engines deal with this problem ? Memory pools?

Comment: custom allocators usually. there are some libraries and talks out there. EA has open sourced their own stl also https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL

Comment: Why are you using `shared_ptr` of all things for something like this?

Comment: Also, please post the compiler options you used to build your application, especially the optimization setting(s).  If this is a "debug" or unoptimized build you're testing, the results are meaningless.

Comment: It's more or less the same with raw pointers. The performance loss due to massive allocations per frame. Those results are in a Release build of course full optimizations. I will check that stl from EA thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details are scant, but I see two opportunities for tuning.

`m_commandBuffer` is a polymorphic container of some kind. I completely understand why you would build it this way, but it presents a problem - each element must be separately allocated.

You may well get much better performance by amalgamating all render operations into a `variant`, and implement m_commandBuffer as a vector (or queue) of such variants. This allows you to `reserve()` space for the 1000 commands with 1 memory allocation, rather than the (at least) 1000 you currently require.

It also means that you only incur the cost of one memory fence during the allocation, again rather than the thousands you are suffering while incrementing and decrementing all the reference counts in all those `shared_ptr`s.

So:

```
using Command = boost::variant< SetShaderValuesCommand, BindMaterialCommand, RenderMeshCommand>;

using CommandQueue = std::deque<Command>;
```

Executing the commands then becomes:

```
for (auto& cmd : m_commandBuffer) {
  boost::apply_visitor([](auto& actualCmd) { 
    actualCmd.run(); /* or whatever is the interface */
  }, cmd);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I discovered std::variant. The problem now is that my commands are not POD, I think that this will not work if my commands hold types like std::string or std::vector. I will try this approach after changing my commands to hold only POD types. Thank you!!

Comment: @FrameBuffer it will work with non-POD types. They must be either move-constructable or moveable, which they certainly will be.

Comment: But those types will call "new" internally to allocate their content no? This will impact performance or am I wrong?

Comment: @FrameBuffer it depends. If the strings are short, no. If they are long, there are many techniques for reducing memory allocations in strings and vectors. One is a custom allocator (see boost's pool allocator). You could for example, allocate one memory pool for each command pass.